# Selection list populated from database

Tags: php, database, list, selection, populate

I have been having a problem trying to figure out how to create a selection list which is populated with data from a table in a database, namely with the options being customer's last names.

Here is what i have tried:

I am trying to make the selection list access the table "customer" and fields "customerID"
Any help would be greatly appreciated, if any more information is needed just ask.

Comment: Is `<?=$options?>` a typo (missing the <?php =$options?>)

Comment: @MisterJ that's shortcode. check this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: Set your `error_reporting` and `display_errors` to _sensible_ debugging levels – so that PHP will tell you where your simple syntax errors are.

Comment: If you are just getting a generic "500 server error", put this at the start of your code and you will get more detailed error information with a line number etc.; `<?php ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
`

Comment: i added that line to the top of my code (as i have edited above) but it still just gives me the generic server error page with no extra information.

Answer (score 1):

You are messing in quotes. Try below.

```
$options .= "<option value='" . $id ."'>" . $name ."</option>";
```

And than use it like,

```
<select>
<option value=0>Choose</option>
<?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Need more what you mean by no luck ? What you getting ?

Comment: i am getting this generic error "Server error The website encountered an error while retrieving tl28serv.uws.edu.au/twa/TWA312/working/task10.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."

Comment: @bigsenator - Your first php tag on top of the file , I can't see you have ended it ? Also check your server error logs to check the error.

Comment: Sorry, yes i noticed that mistake and changed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 "<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">$name </option>";
```

This will prevent names, such as O'mally, from accidental truncation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
$id=$row["customerID"]
$name=$row["lastName"]
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id"\">".$name."</OPTION>;
}
?>

<p>Select a customer's ID to view information on</p>

<select>
<option value=0>Choose</option>
<?=$options?>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id"\">".$name;
```

to this:

```
$options.="<OPTION VALUE='" . $id. "'>" . $name . "</option>";
```

And if you have an error, tell us what error it is?

Comment: I changed my code to what you have shown but i am still getting an error page, the error is just "Server error The website encountered an error while retrieving http://tl28serv.uws.edu.au/twa/TWA312/working/task10.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."

Comment: But i know for sure the server isn't down because i have previously made scripts working fine on there.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a PHP error, more like a server misconfiguration... Try creating a new php file with only <?php phpinfo(); ?> in it. See if it brings you the PHP information page. If it does, everything is working, if not, your server is not working correctly. Then change it to <?php phpbogus(); ?> This should give you a clear and distinct from the previous errorpage, a PHP error.

Comment: When i used <?php phpinfo(); ?> it did in fact take me to the PHP information page

Comment: But <?php phpbogus(); ?> returned a blank page.

Comment: Put this in front of your script: error_reporting(E_ALL); it will turn on all error reporting, showing you what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: you mean like <?php ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>

Comment: I added that to the top of my coding and it doesn't seem to be showing any extra information.